# QGraphicsItem Performance with QML

Tags: performance, qml, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, qobject

I have a QML File which shows a simple Display. I want to update the Text inside the QML File every x seconds.
This already works fine. I'm using QGraphicObjects which I add to a QGraphicsScene.

Now I heard, that QGraphicsObjects are much slower than QGraphicsItems.

So I want to know, if it is possible, to use QML Files as a QGraphicsItem? Or are there other possibillities to use a qml Object with the performance of a QGraphicsItem?

The alternative would be to create my Displays as a QGraphicsItem, but I would prefere doing it in QML.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

QML items need Qt meta-object system, then it's not possible to use QGraphicsItem (which is not QObject).

More slower? What is the real gain with QGraphicsItem? Test it before trying to lose flexibility of QML.

If you have performance problems, the best solution might be to move to Qt Quick 2? (Qt 5.2 if possible, read: https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/09/02/new-scene-graph-renderer)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use openGL. So I can't use Qt Quick 2.

Comment: Ok, then you don't have choice, test performances and use QML/QGraphicsObjects ou QGraphicsItems directly